# Concurrency Design in golang - wait for a certain number of goroutines

Tags: go, wait

I have a list of 10 servers, out of which one of those servers is a *primary*. It has the responsibility of sending a *request* to remaining 9 servers and has to wait for a reply for *at least 5 of them.* I can send these requests asynchronously using goroutines, and once I have received the reply from *at least 5 of them*, I can proceed with my execution. How do I design this using go, in general? Feel free to use any tools you like. You can assume these 10 servers are isolated, and have nothing shared between them.

Comment: What do you mean by "Those remaining 5 goroutines have to be called?" At what point in execution do they need to get before you can move on? This needs to addressed on an architectural level and merits more thought than this quick SO question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are communicating with remote servers, it probably makes sense to have a [`context.Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context#Context) that gets canceled once 5 of your 10 requests complete. You would pass that context to whatever network function you are using.

For example:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
n := int32(10)
// Inside the goroutine
if atomic.AddInt32(&n, -1) == 5 {
    cancel()
}
<-ctx.Done() // returns once the context is canceled
```